# How to save Persian numbers like "۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷ ۸ ۹ ۰" in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, numbers, persian

I set mysql to utf8-general-ci and it has no problem with Persian texts but I have a column as Price and I want it to be INT and in Persian, ofcourse it has no problem with English numbers but as I want to enter Persian numbers like: "۱ ۲ ۳ " and ..., it alerts me that can not recognize what is being entered...
I also tried below things but I've got no answer:

```
mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES UTF8");
mysqli_query($db,"SET CHARACTERS utf8");
mysqli_set_charset($db,'UTF8');
```

and I tried so many Collations in mysql such as:

```
utf8_general_ci
utf8_persian_ci
utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: This is purely a presentational matter—numeric storage is unaffected.

Comment: @eggyal then what should i do?

Comment: Don't do it!  "۱ ۲ ۳ " are characters and not numbers. If you enter them this way, you won't be able to do any db calculations on them.

Answer (score 2):

Simply convert to/from Persian numerals in the *presentation* layer of your application, e.g. using the PHP [intl extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php)'s [`NumberFormatter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#intl.numberformatter-constants.types) class with the `fa` (Farsi) locale:

```php
$persianNumberFormatter = new \NumberFormatter('fa', \NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_STYLE);
var_dump($persianNumberFormatter->format(12345));       // string(12) "۱۲٬۳۴۵"
var_dump($persianNumberFormatter->parse('۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰')); // float(1234567890)
```

Comment: thank you but when i tried, it said that this class NumberFormatter is not exist, the interstiong part was that it has a very good auto completion and snippet but it has error!!

Comment: @Navid: see the manual chapter on [installation](https://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php) of the intl extension.

Comment: would you please help me in my last question? no one answered me ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475181/not-displaying-images-uploaded-in-ubuntu-localhost-because-of-www-data

Answer (score -1):

Use normal arabic numbers and then when you want to show it in your front end do like this:

```
$western_arabic = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$indian_arabic = array('٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩');

$str = str_replace($western_arabic, $indian_arabic, $str);
```

-Note that in English arabic numbers are used whereas in arabic indian numbers are used and it looks like Persians are using a modified version of indian digits where 4, 5 and 6 are different so you have to take care of that in the above example.

Comment: I think the _arrays_ are backward.  Perhaps you want _strings_?  '0123...' and the R-L Persian equivalent?

Comment: Arrangement is not important in this case because it uses str_replace and it has nothing to do with direction (rtl or ltr) because numbers are written the same way in both languages (most languages?) with the most significant digit is the digit farthest to the left.

Comment: But I thought `٠` meant `0`.

Comment: It is. So what?