# not displaying images uploaded in ubuntu localhost because of www-data

Tags: php, mysql, image, ubuntu, permissions

I uploaded image into my test project(it is an online shop) and they are not be displayed where they should(the index.php page of my project)

the directory is `/var/www/html/php/`

It has no problem with inserting the name of picture to database and the upload function work good and transfer images to the `image directory` of project well, but the only problem is that they are not displayed.

I must say that i've tried lots of ways and i granted so many types of users and group permissions and even the unsafe permissions like: `chmod 777` or i take my user `navid` to `www-data` group and vise versa! But it doesn't work.

This is some of my code:

```
//function for adding product
function add_product($product_name, $product_price, $product_cat, $product_desc, $image_name, $image_tmp){
    global $db;
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp, '../images/' . $image_name);
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO products(product_name, product_price, product_cat, product_desc, product_image) VALUES ('$product_name','$product_price', '$product_cat', '$product_desc', '$image_name')");

}
```

this is my `fetch` function:

```
//the fuction to fetch all products from database to show in admin profile
function get_products($limit = 0){
    global $db;
    if ($limit == 0) {//this if works for showing all products if it is 0
        $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC ");
    } else {
        $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit");
    }
    return $query;
}
```

and this is the **action** of adding product and displaying the images:

```
//the action of ADD_PRODUCT
if (isset($_POST['add-product'])) {
    $product_name = $_POST['product-name'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product-price'];
    $product_cat = $_POST['product-cat'];
    $image_name = $_FILES['product-image']['name'];
    $image_tmp = $_FILES['product-image']['tmp_name'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['product-desc'];

    if (add_product($product_name, $product_price, $product_cat, $product_desc, $image_name, $image_tmp)) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $error = "";
    }
}
```

what i use in index page:

```
$products = get_products(6);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVeXJ.png]